# Google Cloud Platform: SSH to Google cloud instance will have "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, public-key

I have come across the  issue as below when I use ssh login google cloud instance

```
$ ssh -i DD2 root@35.237.32.84
Permission denied (publickey).
```

After some testing, I found that the cause of the error is that public key signature is not consistent with the account for google cloud:

For example :

```
scuio33@chef-server:~$
```

here you account is scuio33
then your pub file will be :

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDBpNeFZyXXXehjPuGCkEjb/t
laNQt0fztORSCFFQIoKHkQzi7SNhp48kagyOHDNj6mY1LmVZB/sIj2oCa1AFupoFuBYc/XILP
rTX60fIlnBYkHl+6Kq/TX2hzKv scuio33
```

scuio33 will be exactly same as your google account, or there will have the issue  "Permission denied (publickey)". Only google cloud has this restriction.

This is not a "question". But a hint for ssh to google cloud failure.

Comment: `scuio33 will be exactly same as your google account, or there will have the issue "Permission denied (publickey)"` This doesn't make sense. The "scuio33" field in your public key line is a comment. It doesn't have any effect on how ssh works.

Comment: Just same thought as you at first time, when I using scuio33@XX and other name in the public file as ending, the ssh will not work, and change to scuio33 then work. The issue only occurs on google cloud. Same reference https://mini.nidbox.com/diary/read/8884523 if you know chinese.

Comment: I can conferm this, in 2022.

Comment: If anybody have recently upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 and facing this issue. Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/74273581/11823331

Comment: Can confirm creating a new pair with ed25519 algo works for me. Use the username when creating the key. Username is not my organization email, it was firstname_lastname. Use the SSH browser option in GCP console and find it yourself



`ssh-keygen -o -t ed25519 -C "username_of_VM" `

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I experienced this issue when trying to set up Kubernetes for the first time on Google Cloud Platform.

I was running into the error below each time I tried to SSH into my instance from my terminal:

```
promisepreston@52.174.274.72: Permission denied (publickey)
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

Open a terminal on your workstation and use the `ssh-keygen` command to generate a new key. Specify the `-C` flag to add a comment with your username.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/[KEY_FILENAME] -C [USERNAME]
```

In my case it was:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/kubernetes-trial -C promisepreston
```

Navigate into the `.ssh` directory:

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

Restrict access to your private key so that only you can read it and nobody can write to it.

```
chmod 400 [KEY_FILENAME]
```

In my case it was:

```
chmod 400 kubernetes-trial
```

Double click on `kubernetes-trial.pub` to open it OR print it on the console using the `cat` command:

```
sudo cat kubernetes-trial.pub
```

The public SHH key should be of this format:

```
ssh-rsa [KEY_VALUE] [USERNAME]
```

OR

```
ssh-rsa [KEY_VALUE] google-ssh {"userName":"[USERNAME]","expireOn":"[EXPIRE_TIME]"}
```

In my case it was:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3MzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDdLjLb2b97m9NSK5Z8+j6U8awAwIx1Sbn9o4cEpYT2USYlFhJPRckgnmCQ+Eaim/sgL40V2v3Jwt6HVAY0L9bl84jmvox9QP4FOY7+LM02ZqfRB6LaEukM1tGdObVr+HBvhOwrxGCI06GFjnD3vVzW4jEsK75Y7MPzXd5YSpebGvU+7ZOuEcuSKp/R9dJcJn4kdXeaqor4gh8uTKQ43PGPTEvyoNlCWLkwSgy8khbo2BpoChLA7B53pVEhviMvVVIbmwpc6V2AIhRYY7ppR8oBzklLgh8CtTBPXtQRYiahLOIhds6ORf7wGNFI+A4sbBqwEL3J6av5fE1+zkUBhAHX promisepreston
```

Copy its contents and paste in the SSH Section of your instance under the Metadata section
[Adding or removing instance-level public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only)

[image: ssh keys]

In a local terminal, navigate to the directory where you have the **private SSH key file**, use the `ssh` command along with your **private SSH key file**, the username, and the external IP address of the instance to connect. For example:

```
ssh -i private-key username@external-ip-of-the-virtual-instance
```

In my case it was:

```
ssh -i kubernetes-trial promisepreston@52.174.274.72
```

After you connect, run commands on your instance using this terminal. When you finish, disconnect from the instance by running the `exit` command.

**Note**:

- Ensure that you added the instance-level public SSH keys
  [Adding or removing instance-level public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only)
- Ensure that you are not blocking project-wide public SSH keys from the Linux instance
  [Allowing or blocking project-wide public SSH keys from a Linux instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#block-project-keys)
- Ensure that OS Login is not enabled
  [Enabling or disabling OS Login](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instance-access#enable_oslogin)

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Comment: Bang on the money. I have exactly this problem with GC SSH.

Comment: Thanks! In my case the problem was that OS Login was enabled.

Comment: Excellent step by step tutorial. For people having access to multiple instance removing **config** and **google-cloud-auth** file helped

Answer (score 11):

**You have to make sure that the same username you used to generate the key matches the one from your local cpu.**

---

## Step-by-steps:

#### 1/ Generate the key (no paraphrase)

On local cpu:
By default on linux $USER will give you your username (`echo $USER`), so you don't even need to specify it.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/my_google_cloud_key -C $USER
```

#### 2/ Copy the key to Google Cloud metadata

```
cat /home/$USER/.ssh/my_google_cloud_key.pub
```

Select and copy it in https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata/sshKeys (add key, then save)

#### 3/ Connect to your VM

Get the external IP of your instance at https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

```
EXTERNAL_IP={{input your external ip}}
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_google_cloud_key $USER@$EXTERNAL_IP
```

Comment: You saved me. One small point because I copy blind : there is a missing space between ssh[space]-i.

Answer (score 4):

Connecting with an SSH key to a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance is not limited to the users of the project the instance belongs to. You can generate an SSH key and as long as it’s added to the instance and the user exists on the OS, you should be able to SSH. You can connect with other usernames. Make sure that:

1. You add the public key to the instance via the Google Cloud Console [[1]](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide)
2. Your username exists on the OS of your instance
3. If you want to SSH as "root", change the configuration in your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

Answer (score 2):

Promise Preston`s solution works, just make sure you disable "ENABLE-OSLOGIN" or remove this from the metadata settings.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same error and resolved by unchecking "Block project-wide SSH keys" on the "VM instance details" settings page. Apparently this blocks ssh-ing from your local to GCE instances.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

promise-preston's answer works for me. The problem is that the name not match google account name.

Take into consideration that, if not specified, the name google ssh server recognize is automatically generated based on your email address BUT not necessarily the same. In my case my email address is wenzhan.main@gmail.com, and the user name is actually wenzhan_main. Double check that trick.

One more small thing i want to add on is that, something like `ssh -i kubernetes-trial promisepreston@52.174.274.72`, will only work if you are already in `.ssh/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same error. try to add `--tunnel-through-iap`

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone "%zone%" "%instanaceName%" --project "%projectName%"  --tunnel-through-iap
```

Replace the following:

- %zone% - Enter the zonal (location) name of the compute engine
- %instanceName% - Name of the instance(compute engine)
- %projectName% - Google cloud current project name

Answer (score 1):

I know there are similar answers but I am lost in the answers, easly;

**for the existing ssh key**

1- Copy your public key like the following format, i.e:
`ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDAu5kKQCPF... hbceylan`

2- GCP **>** Edit VM **>** add SSH key **>** SAVE

[image]

3- SSH to the instance
`ssh -i /path-to-private-key/id_rsa hbceylan@1.2.3.4`

**for a new ssh-key**

1- Create an ssh key, i.e:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/x-poject-hbceylan -C hbceylan -b 2048`

2- GCP **>** Edit VM **>** add SSH key **>** SAVE (see picture)

3- SSH to the instance

`ssh -i /path-to-private-key/id_rsa hbceylan@1.2.3.4`

Answer (score 0):

Go to project-level metadata (Compute Engine -> Metadata) and ensure that you have either no enable-oslogin key or that it is set to FALSE.This worked for windows powershell

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I had to add the SSH key inside of "edit [name] instance"-> Security and access --> SSH Keys, I added the .pub key as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, despite uploading the public key to the VM and configuring ssh file in Visual Studio with private key, I was unable to connect, for the same reason.

For me, this is what solved. You follow the steps of adding .pub file to instance metadata, hold you private key in the ssh config file, then run:

```
gcloud compute ssh --zone "your-vm-zone" "your-instance"  --project "your_project"
```

This will generate a id_rsa file recognized by the Google Cloud VM. Then you can connect regularly using SSH, in my case, in Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this as user `jupyter`. Prompted by [@maximusX3's answer, which suggested to make a change in the Metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67867701/199475), I pulled up my [GCP metadata's SSH keys subpage](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/metadata?tab=sshkeys).

Interestingly, when I loaded the page, I had duplicate SSH keys for the `jupyter` user, and the interface automatically prompted me to delete duplicate SSH keys. (You can do this through the GCP interface with one click.) After doing so, I was able to ssh in as jupyter using the usual `gcloud compute ssh jupyter@machine` command without any other local or remote changes.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is not a question, then my answer is not an answer I guess. Anyways, it's not clear what should match what. The comment in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on a CE instance and the user name you provide to an `ssh` command? That's totally not the case:

```
$ ssh u@xx.yyy.xx.yyy cat .ssh/authorized_keys
# Added by Google
ssh-rsa ... yuri@yuri
```

The reason I received "Permission denied (publickey)" was that I was using `gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE` in a `docker` container running as `root`. Like a person [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64477854/52499). And by default this command uses the local user name (`root` in my case). But:

> By default, Compute Engine VMs built from public images and most common operating systems don't allow root login with a password over SSH.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/root-ssh

Launching a CE instance for the first time I was confused. Which user name I should use and how do I add a public key? The answer is, it appears, by adding the key to [project or instance metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#metadata). The user you specify with the key is automatically created. Alternatively you can use [`gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE` or SSH-in-browser](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/standard-ssh#gcloud). But make sure you're not running under `root`, `root` logins are allowed ([`PermitRootLogin`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/core/openssh/sshd_config.5.en#PermitRootLogin)), or you specify a non-`root` username in case of the the `gcloud` command.